Damping resistor for clock signal at the input side?
Im building an audio DAC and the datasheet recommends damping resistors for the I2S signals
e.g

From what I have found about these kind of digital damping resistors is that they are most effective when placed at the driver/source side rather than at the input end.
The I2S interface that I will use with the DAC already includes these damping resistors at its output, so there would be a damping resistors at both ends of the clock trace.
For my case, should I then omit the resistors at the DAC inputs or is there still a reason to keep them?

Damping at source only for series R's

With mixed signal components like this DAC you really want to avoid overshoot and ringing on your digital signals, because input voltage going out of the allowed range will cause the ESD protection diodes to conduct and dump the offending pulse into either GND or VCC. The chip is not harmed, but it can add noise to the internal power rails and couple into the output.

From what I have found about these kind of digital damping resistors is that they are most effective when placed at the driver/source side rather than at the input end.

Yes.
I don't know why they also want to put them on the receiving side. The chip can't be master so these pins are input-only, maybe they have high input capacitance, it's not specified but I don't see why... Besides you're probably going to use short traces, a few cm long. Personally I'd put the resistors if the traces are long, then probe it with a scope, just out of curiosity.

Interesting, thank you for the info on ESD diodes.
